# Unix shell scripting: date format syntax

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, hp-ux

I m trying to get yesterday date, it's not working in hp ux server.

```
Prev_date=$(date +"y%m%d" -d "1 day ago")
```

For this I m still getting current date only.
20210811

Could you please help on the same.

Comment: Already discussed here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517982/in-a-unix-shell-how-to-get-yesterdays-date-into-a-variable

Comment: This is unrelated to any shell, only the version of `date` you are using.

Comment: @chepner, to be precise it is not about version but the release of `date` utility. And AFAIK none of popular unises (AIX, Solaris, HP-UX) support `--date` key

Comment: @user16598664, check the question on the link and see the solution in accepted answer.

Comment: @RomeoNinov By "version", I don't mean a particular numbered release from any particular project. (And if you are going to pretend Unix is a 3rd-declension Latin noun, the plural would be *unices*.)

Comment: @chepner, my latin is "tabula rasa" :D . Get your point about the version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a unix shell, how to get yesterday's date into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517982/in-a-unix-shell-how-to-get-yesterdays-date-into-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You missed a percentage in front of the 'y': this is working fine for me:

```
echo $(date +"%y%m%d" -d "1 day ago")
```

Comment: `echo $(…)` seems superfluous.

Comment: The question is about HP-UX and `--date` is not supported!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command, if you want.

```
date --date=' 1 days ago' '+%Y-%m-%d'
```

It will give result like

```
 2021-09-06
```

I prefer this format since most of the time my scripts include SQL queries for data fetch and hence date is required to filter out data on daily basis.

Comment: The question is about `HP-UX` and `--date` is not supported!